# How to determine if an argument is a pure function pointer?

Tags: c++, function, function-pointers, functor, type-traits

I want to write a trait-checker named is_pure_func_ptr, which can determine if the type is a pure function pointer, as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void f1()
{};

int f2(int)
{};

int f3(int, int)
{};

struct Functor
{
    void operator ()()
    {}
};

int main()
{
    cout << is_pure_func_ptr<decltype(f1)>::value << endl; // output true
    cout << is_pure_func_ptr<decltype(f2)>::value << endl; // output true
    cout << is_pure_func_ptr<decltype(f3)>::value << endl; // output true
    cout << is_pure_func_ptr<Functor>::value << endl;      // output false
    cout << is_pure_func_ptr<char*>::value << endl;        // output false
}
```

My question is: **How to implement it?**

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pure"? The Functor one looks pretty pure to me, for some definition of pure.

Comment: @Mat, my examples are meant to define what "pure function pointer" is.

Comment: The thing is, [pure functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) is a well established term. So your question is a bit confusing. Maybe replace with "plain/toplevel functions, not member functions, lambdas or other callable objects" if that's what you mean?

Comment: Yes, your opion is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by Joachim Pileborg, [`std::is_function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) will do the job. 
If that isn't an option for you, but you do have C++11 support (meaning you just want to know how to implement it yourself or your standard library isn't there yet), you could do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_pure_func_ptr: public std::false_type {};
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct is_pure_func_ptr<Ret(Args...)>: public std::true_type {};//detecting functions themselves
template<typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct is_pure_func_ptr<Ret(*)(Args...)>: public std::true_type {};//detecting function pointers
```

[This works](http://ideone.com/53hjDt), but you might need additional work when it comes to supporting functions with different calling conventions and/or cv-qualified pointers

Comment: Many thanks. Grizzly. Your solution is concise and beautiful!

Answer (score 3):

If you have a C++11 standard library, try [`std::is_function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function).

Comment: OP wants it to return false for functors

Comment: Yes. I want to defferentiate pure function pointers and functors.

Comment: @KarthikT And as used in the OPs example, it does.

Comment: Oh sorry.. must be getting sleepy, miss-read the description, +1